# Error al compilar APK Relase en React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Tengo mi proyecto, al correrlo con `react-native run-android` todo está bien.

Pero al generar el *APK* para produccion me manda un error.

---

> *$~ ProjectAwesome/android*
>
> *$ ./gradlew assembleRelease*
>
> *Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.*
>
> *Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.*
>
> *Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.2.*

Recordar que ya generé la keystore a como lo está en el tutorial de la página de documentación de React ([documentación aquí](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html))

Comment: Esto puede ser relacionado a varios problemas en la configuración, desde el targetSDK definido, uso de compile en lugar de implementation, etc, te sugiero agregues tus archivos build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intente generar la `apk` con lineas de comando pero no funcionó, lo intenté con **`android studio`** y lo generó correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Te cuento a mi me paso algo asi por el estilo y hay que revisar bien que la configuración de los paquetes utilizados que use react-native link tengan el targetSDK correcto que vayan de acuerdo al de tu proyecto, ademas nunca pude sacar la aplicación con el comando de react-native, por lo que sugiero que uses una generada con android studio y guardarla en tu proyecto para que no se pierda y pues esa seria una alternativa :D espero te ayude provisionalmente...